# Node modules packages are deleted in Azure function after restart the service

Tags: unix, azure-functions, puppeteer

I want to install puppeteer in Azure linux function. I couldn't install in home directory. I can able to install root directory. But after restart the service the installed packages are deleted. can anyone suggest the solution to install puppeteer in Azure function

Comment: How did you install in root directory? Did you use a script?

Comment: @Md.AbuTaher No. I have used ssh console and run below command.           
    npm install puppeteer

Comment: Serverless does not work that way, anything you run will be gone on next run/invocation. You need to prepare a script or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node#dependency-management. Kudu is not available for Linux, so specifically try the "Deploying with dependencies" part.